# Table structure in sql

Tags: database-design

I need to know the best way we can do the table structure in sql.
I am having 3 Entities. Privileges, Roles and Users. A user can have multiple roles and roles can have different privileges. Can anyone suggest me in what best way we can design table structure in sql.

Comment: There is no best way to organize a database. Everything depends on your particular application. Try something and see what happens. If something goes wrong, you'll be able to ask a specific question here.

Answer (score 1):

> A user can have multiple roles and roles can have different
>   privileges.

We can help you only with respect to identifying number of tables. Other table structure might be very relative to your application, database vendor etc.

Your above statement hints **Many to Many Relationship** ( Graph relationship ) which is as below:

User **<-- User can have many roles  and Role also can pertain to many users -->** Role

Role **<-- Role can have many priviledges and Priviledges also can pertain to many Roles -->** Privileges

So Semantically I see 3 Entity tables and 2 mapping table which are as follows.

**Entity Tables:**
User 
Role
Priviledge

**Mapping Tables:**
User_Roles
Role_priviledges

** Many to Many relationship mostly introduces third table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Users table should have a many-to-many relationship to your Roles table and your Roles table should have a many-to-many relationship to your Privileges table.

You can do this via intersection entities (UserRoles and RolePrivileges) that only have foreign keys to both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Many to many relationships mostly introduces need of third table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create below table (for huge data)

1- User

2- Privileges(Master)

3- Roles (Master)

Now You have create bridge table of Privileges-Roles and User-Roles

4- UserRolesBridge (Row wise data of roles for users)

5- RolesPrivilegesBridge (Row wise data of privileges for Roles )